# is there a way to assign id or classname to an element through document.createElement?

Tags: javascript, html

Im still relatively new to JS. I know i probably shouldnt write my code the way i have done here in the real world, but im only doing this to test my knowledge on for loops and pulling JSON data.

My question is, with the way i have structured my code, is it possible for me to add classnames/Id's to the elements i have made using doc.createElement? for example if i wanted to add custom icons or buttons to each element? I cant seem to think of a way to add them other than having to write out all the HTML and do it that way. Here's my code :

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
    </section>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
const allCustomers = document.querySelector("section");

let custName = "";
let username = "";
let email = "";
let id = "";

const requestURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

fetch(requestURL)
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((text) => DisplayUserInfo(text));

function DisplayUserInfo(userData) {
  const userArray = JSON.parse(userData);

  for (i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++) {
    let listContainer = document.createElement("div");
    let myList = document.createElement("p");
    let myListItems = document.createElement("span");
    myList.textContent = `Customer : ${userArray[i].name}`;
    myListItems.innerHTML =`<br>ID: ${userArray[i].id} <br>Email: ${userArray[i].email} <br>Username: ${userArray[i].username}`; 
    myListItems.appendChild(myList);
    listContainer.appendChild(myListItems);
    allCustomers.appendChild(listContainer);
  }
}

DisplayUserInfo();
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated as well as any constructive feedback. Thanks

Comment: `listContainer.id = 'someid'`. `listContainer.classList.add('someclass')`

Comment: You need to declare `i` in that function with `let`

Comment: Duly noted Pointy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `document.createElement` it returns an `Element`. You can use `Element` attributes and methods to reach what you need. There are some [docs for this class on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element).

This means you can:

```js
> myDiv = document.createElement("div")
<div></div>
> myDiv.id = "test"
'test'
> myDiv
<div id="test"></div>
```

For classes you can use the attributes `className` or `classList`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for sure you can add any attribute for a created element. `element.classList.add('class-name-here')` for adding class, `element.id = 'id-name-here'` for adding id.

```js
const allCustomers = document.querySelector("section");

let custName = "";
let username = "";
let email = "";
let id = "";

const requestURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

fetch(requestURL)
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((text) => DisplayUserInfo(text));

function DisplayUserInfo(userData) {
  const userArray = JSON.parse(userData);

  for (i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++) {
    let listContainer = document.createElement("div");
    let myList = document.createElement("p");
    myList.classList.add('active');
    myList.id = 'paragraph'
    let myListItems = document.createElement("span");
    myList.textContent = `Customer : ${userArray[i].name}`;
    myListItems.innerHTML =`<br>ID: ${userArray[i].id} <br>Email: ${userArray[i].email} <br>Username: ${userArray[i].username}`; 
    myListItems.appendChild(myList);
    listContainer.appendChild(myListItems);
    allCustomers.appendChild(listContainer);
  }
}

DisplayUserInfo();
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}

#paragraph {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
    </section>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible for me to add classnames/Id's to the elements i have
> made using doc.createElement

**Yes** possible with [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) for adding `class` and [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to add `id`

```js
let listContainer = document.createElement("div");
// To add class
listContainer.className = 'your-class'; //if you have just one
listContainer.classList.add("my-class");//if you want to add multiple
// To add id
listContainer.setAttribute("id", "your_id");
```

Comment: Brilliant , thanks alot for the speedy response

Comment: Welcome Chris, is it respond to your question?